# How to slice a list that contains two list for each?

Tags: python, list, slice, python-3.6

I am trying to select the first list in each row and return them as list 
using the slicing methods:

```
l = [[[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], [0.0]],
     [[1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2], [0.0]],
     [[0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0], [0.0]],
     [[1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2], [0.0]],
     [[1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0], [0.0]],
     [[0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [0.0]],
     [[0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2], [0.0]],
     [[0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2], [0.0]],
     [[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2], [0.0]],
     [[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0.0]]]

# i want to get this 

l1 = [[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
     [1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2],
     [0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0],
     [1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2],
     [1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0],
     [0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
     [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2],
     [0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
     [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2],
     [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
list(map(lambda x: x[0], l))
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
 [1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2],
 [0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2],
 [1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0],
 [0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2],
 [0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
 [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: Glad to hear it works, I would be happy if you accept the answer then :)